# Access case statement to return value from mutliple fields

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm struggling to write a case statement in Access VBA to perform what should be the relatively straight forward task of refering to a certain field when a case is met.

Say I have a table witgh ID, Product Type, QTY, Amount, Total

QTY, Amount and Total all mean the same thing, but where this is shown in the table is dependant on the product type. ie if product type is 1 then the 'QTY' field will be populated, if product type = 2 then the 'Amount' field will be populated.

What I'm trying to do is write a function for a query that refers to a specific field for the result and produces something like this:

If Type = 1, then refer to Quantity for the result, If type = 2, then refer to Total for the result etc. I used an iif statement before to refer to the correct column (iif( [MainTable]![Type] = "1",[main table]![Quantity],) but there are too many variables for 'Type' in my real table so this won't do anymore..

```
Public Function TotalAmount(Type As String)

    Select Case Type

        Case "1"
            TotalAmount = "Quantity"

        Case "2"
            TotalAmount = "Total"

        Case "3"
            TotalAmount = "Amount"

    End Select
```

I'm pretty new to coding so I've got no idea how to refer to particular field for the result and this is as far as I've got.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a `Switch` expression in your query to evaluate those cases and return the value of the correct field.  (You might not need a custom VBA function for this.)

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    [Product Type],
    Switch
        (
            [Product Type] = '1', [QTY],
            [Product Type] = '2', [Total],
            [Product Type] = '3', [Amount]
        ) As TotalAmount
FROM YourTable;
```

Note the `Switch` logic is similar to the `Select Case` you were using in your VBA function.  So I hope this suggestion is reasonably clear.  If not clear enough, look at the *Switch Function* topic in Access' built-in help system.

In a comment, you indicated you want `[Amount]` as the returned field when `[Product Type]` is "3", "4", or "5".  You can adapt the `Switch` suggestion to accomplish that ...

```sql
    Switch
        (
            [Product Type] = '1', [QTY],
            [Product Type] = '2', [Total],
            [Product Type] In ('3','4','5'), [Amount]
        ) As TotalAmount
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Hans. The switch function works correctly when I enter it into the builder with seperate expressions, but I can't seem to get the "Or" Operator working?

I want to state that the following:

Amount: Switch([Table1]![Type]="1",[Table1]![QTY],[Table1]![Type]="2",[Table1]![Total],[Table1]![Type]="3" Or "4" Or "5",[Table1]![Table1]![Amount])

I've tried creating a fucntion for this using what you provided but can't get that to work either...

Thanks Again!

Comment: I'm still not sure how to enter this as a function?

Comment: Perhaps we are not on the same page.  I suggested `Switch` in a query as an alternative to creating a custom VBA function.  Are you still intent on creating a function anyway?

Comment: I think a custom VBA function would be cleaner and would be easier to update.. And there are a number of product types that choose the same result so it seems unnecessary to duplicate the same code..

Comment: I've tried using what you reccomended in a query but it doesn't look like it accepts the 'In' and 'As' parts?

Comment: I fixed a mistake in the answer --- there should not be an equal sign in this piece: `[Product Type] In ('3','4','5'), [Amount]`

Comment: I saw your suggested edit.  It makes me wonder does the following query work if you paste it into SQL View of a new query in the Access query designer ...

Comment: `SELECT Switch( [Asset Type]= 'FXO',[Net Amount (Local)], [Asset Type]= 'CDS_IX',[Principal], [Asset Type] In('ISO', 'IXO','CFD','EQIX','EQS'), [Quantity/Current Face], [Asset Type]= 'CDS_SN',[Swap Nominal Par], [Asset Type] In('SWO','BASIS','CAP','CBS','CCSW','IRS','LPI','PPARIL','PPARNOM', 'PRCDIL','PRCDNOM','RPI','RRS','TRS_IL','TRS_NOM','ZCS'), [Swap Receivable Leg - Nominal Par]) As switch_expression FROM TradeFile`